# How to get innerText of an element by referencing its id?

Tags: vba, excel

Code Masters!

Newbie here! I was trying to create a tool for scraping texts from a website using .innerText method by referencing elements by its id, but with some ids I only get spaces and/or breaks.

Here's the webpage's source code:

```html
<div id="empName">
  <h2>Employee Name</h2>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <span style="font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold">
    <div id="empID">Employee ID</div>
  </span>
```

Here's my VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SampleCode()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument
Dim EmployeeName As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim EmployeeID As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim URL As String

URL = "www.example"

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .FullScreen = True
    .Navigate URL
End With

Do
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And IE.Busy <> True

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
Set EmployeeName = HTMLDoc.getElementById("empName")
Set EmployeeID = HTMLDoc.getElementById("empID")

Debug.Print EmployeeName.tagName, EmployeeName.innerText, EmployeeID.tagName, EmployeeID.innerText

IE.FullScreen = False
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here's the result as shown from Immediate Window:

```
DIV           Employee Name           DIV
```

I followed tutorials from YouTube but I couldn't get the text from "empID" id attribute. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: It might be dynamically filled with JavaScript based on some event. Does it show up in browser if you disable JavaScript? You can also check `EmployeeID.outerHTML` to confirm

Comment: @Slai, I tried disabling JavaScript and a lot of information don't show up in the browser including "Employee ID"; running the code with .outerHTML, I get this result: <div id="empID"></div>

Comment: Is that HTML from "view source" or the actual rendered HTML as from (eg) your browser's Developer Tools?  Your code looks fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I copied it from DOM Explorer. As Slai pointed out, I need to wait for the JavaScript to kick in. I thought, .ReadyState=4 means IE has finished loading and processing any script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try waiting until the text is filled:

```
timeout = Now + #0:00:05#  ' to wait up to 5 seconds

While EmployeeID.innerText = "" And Now < timeout 
    DoEvents
Wend

Debug.Print EmployeeID.innerText
```

Comment: Got it! It worked. Thank you very much, @Slai. So, I need to wait for the JavaScript to kick in? I thought loop until .readystate=4 is enough.

Comment: @alvin I am guessing it waits for the document to be fully loaded and ready before populating the content, so it's probably a bit after READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Comment: Okay, gotcha! I'll keep that in mind. Thank you very much, @Slai. I really appreciate your help.